# SQL Server - Code for Updating values using inner query self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

this may be quite basic for most, but I'd like to get some help.

Using SQL Server I have the following Orders table (Excel excerpt to simplify):

[image: Simplified Excel Excerpt]

Please note there are multiple orders (OrderID). Some may have "PrimaryOrder" value, meaning they are related to an existing prior order. Related orders receive the "PrimaryOrder" of the 1st related order, and an "OrderIndex" noting the order they came in.
Only the first order in each set has value. If an order's "PrimaryOrder" is NULL, it means it is a single order and I should simply ignore it.

What I need is, using SQL Server Update command give all orders which are related, the same "value" as their 1st related order's "Value".
Meaning for each order that has "OrderIndex" > 1, update it's Value field from NULL to it's "PrimaryOrder" value.
If "PrimaryOrder" = 1 OR is NULL, ignore and don't update.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Tried some simple INNER JOIN but got lost.
I don't think it should be too complicated, but I might be overthinking it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* sub-query with `update` statement :

```
update o
     set o.value = (select top (1) o1.value
                    from Orders o1 
                    where o1.primaryorder = o.primaryorder and 
                          o1.value is not null and
                          o1.orderindex <= o.orderindex
                    order by o1.orderindex desc
                   )
from Orders o
where o.value is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
UPDATE #table
SET a.Value=b.Value
FROM #table a INNER JOIN #table b 
        on a.OrderID=b.PrimaryOrder and a.OrderIndex>1 and a.Value is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE o
SET Value=MaxVals.MaxValue
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Value) AS MaxValue, PrimaryOrder
    FROM Orders
    WHERE PrimaryOrder IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY PrimaryOrder
) AS MaxVals ON MaxVals.PrimaryOrder=o.PrimaryOrder
WHERE o.Value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
Managed to take something from all the above and this solved it:

```
UPDATE O
    SET O.[Value] = B.[Value]
FROM Orders O INNER JOIN Orders B
ON O.PrimaryOrder = B.[PrimaryOrder] and O.OrderIndex > 1 and O.[Value] is NULL
AND B.[OrderIndex] = 1
```